# How do I redirect all but one url to a script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get www.example.com and www.example.com/index.html to go to index.html, but I want all other urls e.g. www.example.com/this/is/another/link to still show www.example.com/this/is/another/link but be processed by a generic script. I've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mygenericscript.php [L]
```

but it wont work, can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of testing what `%{REQUEST_URI}` is, you can instead just test if the resource exists:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* mygenericscript.php
```

This prevents your static resources (images, stylesheets, etc.) from being redirected if they're handled through the same directory your `.htaccess` is in as well.

What's probably happening now is that you're seeing an internal server error, caused by an infinite internal redirection loop when you try to access anything that isn't `/` or `/index.html`. This is because `.*` matches every request, and after you rewrite to `mygenericscript.php` the first time, the rule set is reprocessed (because of how `mod_rewrite` works in the context that you're using it in).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to do this is to install a 404-handler which gets executed when the server does not find a file to display.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /mygenericscript.php
```

or

```
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/handler.cgi
```

or similar should do the trick.

It is not that RewriteRule's can not be used for this, it is just that they are tricky to set up and requires in depth knowledge on how apache handles requests. It is a bit of a black art.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you're using PHP, and you can use auto_x_file (x is either append or prepend:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php